# PATCH Method not allowed

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I tried to add a Patch method to my API in Django and I'm always ending with a "Method not allowed".

I added mixins.UpdateModelMixin as mention in the Django Rest Framework documentation, however, it still returns the same error. I look and don't find where I need to put authorization for Patch to be allowed.

this is the code related to that view and path declaration in urls.py and views.py.

**urls.py**

```
schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
        title="WAF Management Portal API",
        default_version="v1",
        description="REST api for interaction between Frontend and Backend.",
        contact=openapi.Contact(email="soc-dev-automation@bell.ca"),
    ),
    public=True,
    permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
)

path(
        'action/dothis/', ActionApiView.as_view(), name="action_api_view"
    ),
```

**views.py**

```
class ActionApiView(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, ActionAPIView):
    """
    post:
        add one or more settings to selected policy

    patch:
        modify or more settings to selected policy

    """

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Policy.objects.allowed_to_user(self.request.user)

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return SettingsSerializer(*args, **kwargs)

    @swagger_auto_schema()
    def post(self, request):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            selected_policies = serializer.get_selected_policies(queryset)

            .....do some data manipulation (included action_id variable)...

            response = {
                ....prepare response
            }

            return redirect("another_view", action_id=action_id)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    @swagger_auto_schema()
    def patch(self, request):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            selected_policies = serializer.get_selected_policies(queryset)

            .....do some data manipulation (included action_id variable)...

            response = {
                ....prepare response
            }

            return redirect("another_view", action_id=action_id)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: What is ActionAPIView?

Answer (score 0):

If `ActionAPIView` is inheriting from `ModelViewSet` , you may need to rename the patch function to `update` and change your urls to

```
path(
    'action/dothis/', ActionApiView.as_view({'patch':'update'}), name="action_api_view"
),
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution and it works fine. thank you very much.

Comment: @yuki you should accept this answer if it works for you